# show that collection of all sub-intervals of the form $(a,b]$ of $(0,1]$ is a semi field

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\Omega$ be the interval $(0,1]$. Let $S$ be the collection of all sub-intervals of the form $(a,b]$. Show that $S$ is a semi-field.

This seems pretty easy as I only need to show that $S$ follows the two properties of a semi-field:

1. closed under finite intersection,
2. for any $A\in S$, $A^c$ is a finite disjoint union of sets from $S$.

$S$ can simply be written as $$S=\{(a,b]:0<a<b\le1\}.$$
However, for the first property to hold I need to prove that $\phi$ (empty set) $\in S$ because it is possible to have an empty intersection of a finite number of sub-intervals. However, from the definition of $S$ I can't figure how to show this. Is it because $a\le b$ is a perfectly valid sub-interval (not $a<b$ as assumed)? That would solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, you should allow $a=b$ so that $(a,b]$ becomes $\emptyset$.